# Vue not loading when using extract() in Laravel Mix

Tags: vue.js, webpack, laravel-mix

I have a nearly vanilla webpack.mix.js and resources/js/app.js setup going in my Laravel project.

webpack.mix.js:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

resources/js/app.js:

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('profile', require('./components/profile/Profile.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

But if I tack on `.extract()` to the end in my webpack.mix.js, everything compiles successfully but Vue doesn't load at all in the browser.  Remove the `.extract()` and everything works again.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mix.extract()` (without arguments) splits the usual  `app.js` into three files

- Application Code: app.js
- Vendor Libraries: vendor.js
- Manifest (webpack Runtime): manifest.js

So you'd have to include the other scripts in your Blade view as well for Vue to load

```html
<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{{ mix('js/manifest.js') }}" defer></script>
<script src="{{ mix('js/vendor.js') }}" defer></script>
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
```

The order is somewhat important because the Vue instance is created and mounted in `app.js` while the library itself is in `vendor.js` and the `manifest.js` is the webpack runtime

From the [docs](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/5.0/extract#library-code-splitting)

If you don't provide an array of npm libraries to the extract method, Mix will extract all imported libraries from the node_modules directory. This is a useful default and is likely what you want. However, if you need to be explicit, pass an array and only those vendor libraries will be extracted.

#### What's That Manifest File?

Webpack compiles with a small bit of run-time code, to assist with its job.

When not using `mix.extract()`, this code is invisible to you and lives inside your bundle file.

However, if we want to split our code and allow for long-term caching, that runtime code needs to live somewhere.
As such, mix will extract it to its own file as well. This way, both your vendor and manifest files can be cached as long as possible.